# QM Propagator Question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, greens-functions, propagator

On page 577 of Shankar's 'Principles of Quantum Mechanics' the author gives the Schrodinger propagator:

$$U_s(\textbf{r},t;\textbf{r}',t')=\sum_{n}\psi_n(\textbf{r})\psi^*_n(\textbf{r}')\exp[-iE_n(t-t')].\tag{1}$$

From this we can get

$$\left( i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-H \right)U_s = 0.\tag{2}$$

To stop the propagator propagating backward in time, he introduces the function

$$G_s(\textbf{r},t;\textbf{r}',t')=\theta(t-t')U_s(\textbf{r},t;\textbf{r}',t').\tag{3}$$

Shankar then states that $G_s$ obeys the equation

$$\left( i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-H \right)G_s=\left[ i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\theta(t-t') \right]\sum_{n}\psi_n(\textbf{r})\psi^*_n(\textbf{r}')\exp[-iE_n(t-t')]\tag{4}$$

In equation $(4)$ it is implied that

$$H\left[\theta(t-t')\sum_{n}\psi_n(\textbf{r})\psi^*_n(\textbf{r}')\exp[-iE_n(t-t')]\right]=0.\tag{5}$$

My question is how do we know or show that equation $(5)$ is true?

Comment: Sorry if it was misleading. This part of the book is a chapter on relativistic QM and this section is on the derivation of the Feynmann propagator. Changed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation 5 isn't true. $\Theta(t-t')$ is a scalar/non-operator. Just use the product rule with the derivative, and you'll get:
$$[i\partial_t - H][\Theta(t-t')U_s] = iU_s\partial_t\Theta(t-t') + \Theta(t-t')[i\partial_t - H]U_s.$$

Also, I've never heard the "To stop the propagator propagating backward in time," line. What's going on is you're using the propagator to construct the [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) for the Schrödinger equation, which is a slightly different concept. Short version: $\Theta(t-t')$ is the Green's function for $\partial_t$. The Green's function of $\partial_t + \gamma$ is $\Theta(t-t') e^{-\gamma(t-t')}$. The rest is playing around with eigenvalues and reconstructing the operator.